Is it possible to generate .rdl/.rdlc files using C#?
This is my use case :
The user will select any number of records from a list of records populated in the UI. Based on the selected records, I need to display a Chart report in the web browser. I am trying to create a report definition file in the backend using C# for this selected data.
I need to have the .rdl/.rdlc files created and saved in the API server, so that I can access the files to view the report.
Can someone insist me on how to achieve this?

You can write your report definition in Visual Studio with Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 2022 enxtension - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio2022, or using other tools as Report Builder - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-report-builder?view=sql-server-ver16.
Then you can publish your reports to a SSRS server, which then you can call from your C# API app to render the report.
I think this might be the relevant tutorial for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/tutorial-create-a-quick-chart-report-offline-report-builder?view=sql-server-ver16

Thanks @Robert. This is really helpfull.
